# I am trying to create a route in swift between two points but the route doesn't come out and there is no error

Tags: swift, mkmapview, xcode8, mkoverlay

I am new to swift 3, needed some help.

I am trying to generate a route between two locations. I did implement the method MKOverlayRenderer but the route isn't showing and there is no error.

Here's the code :

```
func initWalkMap()
{
    let point1 = MKPointAnnotation()
    let point2 = MKPointAnnotation()

    point1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userLatitude!, self.userLongitude!)
    point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.destLat!, self.destLong!)
    //point2.title = self.guideName;
    //point2.subtitle = self.categoryName;
    mapView.addAnnotation(point2)
    mapView.centerCoordinate = point2.coordinate
    mapView.selectAnnotation(point2, animated: true);

    //Span of the map
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(point2.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1,0.1)), animated: true)

    let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    let markTaipei = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point1.coordinate.latitude, point1.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
    let markChungli = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point2.coordinate.latitude, point2.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)

    directionsRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: markChungli)
    directionsRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: markTaipei)

    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.walking
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)

    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
        response, error in

        if error == nil {
            self.myRoute = response!.routes[0] as MKRoute
            self.mapView.add(self.myRoute.polyline)
        }
    })
}

//Design to draw polyline
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    let myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: myRoute.polyline)
    myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
    return myLineRenderer
}
```

Comment: The render overlay method is a delegate method, did you set the mapView's delegate and conform to the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol?

Comment: just added the mapView delegate, and it works thx alot bro!